# How do you handle an action (verb) which results in multiple possible state changes with REST

Tags: rest

The scenario is a turn based rpg REST service. Most of the game can be modeled as hypermedia resources however I'm having trouble with one particular use-case. An avatar wants to attack a monster. You can't have the client generate the end-state, to prevent cheating the server needs to decide if there is a miss or a hit and if a hit, how many hit points to subtract. We'd also want reliability and de-duping.

Published base URL:

```
Req:
GET /game
Res:
HTTP/1.1 200
<world>
 <link rel="avatars" href="/avatars"/>
 <link rel="monsters" href="/monsters"/>
</world>
<link rel="actions" href="/actionqueue"/>
```

Skipping the obvious avatars and monsters collection listing.

```
Req:
GET /avatars/1
Res:
HTTP/1.1 200
<avatar>
 <name>Puck</name>
 <health>high</health>
 <link rel="weapon" href="/weapon/3">dagger</link>
</avatar>

Req:
GET /monsters/2
Res:
HTTP/1.1 200
<monster>
 <type>snake</type>
 <health>high</health>
 <state>angry</state>
</monster>
```

Get a server generated unique resource that we don't care about duplicating in case of a lost message.

```
Req:
POST /actionqueue
<action/>
Res:
HTTP/1.1 201
Location:/actionqueue/1234
```

Our idempotent action method.

```
Req:
PUT /actionqueue/1234
<action>
 <type>attack</type>
 <source>
  <avatar>1</avatar>
 </source>
 <target>
  <monster>2</monster>
 </target>
</action>
Res:
HTTP/1.1 200
<outcome>
 <status>success</status>
 <updated>
  <link rel="monster" href="/monsters/2"/>
 </updated>
</outcome>
```

So the question here is about the attack action. It feels kind of RPC like to me but how do you handle something like this? The client can't know the state change in advance so the client has to send "something" to the server to initiate the server decided state change. Is there any better technique? Would you still consider this a RESTful design?

Comment: Can't you directly POST to an 'action' resource? Where do you fear to lose a message?

Comment: POST is not idempotent. If a client doesn't receive the response from from POSTing an action was it because the POST didn't make it to the server or because the response didn't make it to the client? We need retries and uniqueness. Only the first PUT to a specific id would actually give back a 200. See http://www.prescod.net/reliable_http.html and http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-nottingham-http-poe-00.txt.

Comment: What I'm more interested in is the 'action' resource? Is that a good way to solve the multiple possible outcome problem? It just feels like RPC disguised as REST to me. What is the best RESTful design for a Schrödinger's cat problem?

Comment: As for 'action': it feels to me very much the same like a money transfer between bank accounts. I personnally would consider it a resource: it's a noun, has properties, ... See http://www.infoq.com/articles/subbu-allamaraju-rest for the bank account transfer.

Comment: I would try to stick to the REST philosophy and use POST for creating actions. If it turns out transmissions get lost, I would add the POE mechanism - which I discovered from your link above (thx).